# Keycloak : Can I take account IP address when deciding to block a user?

Tags: keycloak

I work on web project which use keycloak for authentication. 
Can I take account IP address when deciding to block a user ?
Example : if user authentication is faillure 5 times, I will block the IP address.

Best regards.

Comment: did below solution work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is similar to brute force attack. As per [keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/server_admin/topics/threat/brute-force.html), they provide feature to disable a user temporarily in case of brute force attacks.

> The way this works is that if there are Max Login Failures during a
>   period of Failure Reset Time, the account is temporarily disabled for
>   the Wait Increment multiplied by the number of failures over the max.
>   After Failure Reset Time is reached all failures are wiped clean.

But a disadvantage, which they have mentioned is that the server becomes vulnerable to denial of service attacks.

They recommend using a third party tool: [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which can be pointed to keycloak log file and can be used to block certain IP addresses.